# Windows 7 won't let me connect to my Ubuntu samba share

Tags: networking, windows-7, samba, file-sharing

I set up samba on my 12.04 Ubuntu install.  I shared a folder from my home directory.

When I go to my Windows 7 box, I can see the Ubuntu box on the network, but when I try to connect, I get a "**Windows Security**" prompt to enter my network password, but entering my password doesn't work.

Comment: Which password are you entering?

Comment: the usernames and passwords on both linux and windows are the same.  I also added a samba user with the same password that maps to the linux user.  On windows, it appears to be asking for the windows user, since the domain it specifies is the name of the windows machine.

Comment: just for a test share a folder outside your home, for example at /home to see if it works